# If I were, I wouldn't have

Tags: subjunctives

> 1. If I were your brother, I wouldn't have approved.
> 2. If I had a knife in my hand, I might have stabbed him.

Do these two sound correct?

Answer (score 1):

The second example should be
*If I had had a knife in my hand, I might have stabbed him.*
for correct sequence of tenses. The first "had" is a marker of perfect tense, and the second "had" is the past tense of "have", to possess.

The first example is alright because being a brother is a permanent relationship. If it were some other relationship, the "if" clause should be in perfect tense:
*If I had been with you, I wouldn't have approved.*

Answer (score 0):

They both work, but I think it would be more appropriate to use a semicolon ";", because they are not joined by a conjunction. If you did use a conjunction to join the sentences, then a comma would necessary.

For example:

1. I wouldn't have approved, **if** I were your bother.
2. I might have stabbed him, **if** I had a knife [in my hand].

Does this help you?